# An array of char arrays, which is a scanner (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, char, java.util.scanner

I can't figure out how to do an array of char arrays, and even worse, an array which is a "scanner" (System.in). I'll explain:

```
1 = A, J, S.
2 = B, K, T.
3 = C, L, U.
4 = D, M, V.
5 = E, N, W.
6 = F, O, X.
7 = G, P, Y.
8 = H, Q, Z.
9 = I, R.
```

I want to input a name, and receive(output) from each letter the equivalent number. But I don't know how to do it. Example:

```
Ericson = 5993165.
```

But I don't want to have an entire number, I want to each number to be a completely independent index, because I want to "calculate names".

Here's an example that I was trying without a scanner:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] arrays = new int[9][3];

}
```

Where each index of the 9-array is a char array with 3 letters. Maybe I'm thinking in a completely wrong way.

I thank you all very much for the attention!

EDIT:

I'm experimenting something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[][][][] Array1 = {{{{1},{'A'},{'J'},{'S'}}}};
    char[][][][] Array2 = {{{{2},{'B'},{'K'},{'T'}}}};
    char[][][][] Array3 = {{{{3},{'C'},{'L'},{'U'}}}};
    char[][][][] Array4 = {{{{4},{'D'},{'M'},{'V'}}}};
    char[][][][] Array5 = {{{{5},{'E'},{'N'},{'W'}}}};
    char[][][][] Array6 = {{{{6},{'F'},{'O'},{'X'}}}};
    char[][][][] Array7 = {{{{7},{'G'},{'P'},{'Y'}}}};
    char[][][][] Array8 = {{{{8},{'H'},{'Q'},{'Z'}}}};
    char[][][] Array9 = {{{9},{'I'},{'R'}}};
    System.out.println('E'+'R'+'I'+'C'+'S'+'O'+'N');
}
```

It's better than my earlier thoughts, but I think I'm far yet. (Again, the major problem is: This "ericson" needs to be a scanner, because the name is not a definite variable. It could be anything.)

Comment: Your example actually is not an example at all, it is you just defining an array of arrays. What have you tried to actually solve your problem ?

Comment: You need some kind of File IO - like a bufferedstreamreader or some network stuff. Scanner is perfectly suited for what you're attempting. Just dump each line into an ArrayList from String to char array like this:  someString.toCharArray()

Answer (score 0):

you want a char, why are you not declaring the array as char

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

char[][] arrays = new char[][] {
  { 'A', 'J', 'S' },
  { 'B', 'K', 'T' },
  { 'C', 'L', 'U' },
  { 'D', 'M', 'V' },
  { 'E', 'N', 'W' },
  { 'F', 'O', 'X' },
  { 'G', 'P', 'Y' },
  { 'H', 'Q', 'Z' },
  { 'I', 'R', '*' }
} ;

}
```

Then have a nested for loop that goes through the array to find the letter and return the row number+1 because it starts at 0
then put the number+1 in an arraylist

```
ArrayList<int> myArr = new ArrayList<int>();
myarr.add(i);
```

Any arraylist is like an array but it doesnt have a fixed size and you can keep adding to it. This keeps all the numbers individual and not as a whole.

Comment: Thank you very much RandomGuy. Pretty useful! I'm still figuring out how to combine "char[][]", "for", "ArrayList" and "BufferedReader" to solve my problem.

Comment: "ArrayList<int>" gives me the following error:
"Syntax error on token "int", Dimensions expected after this token"

I found "ArrayList" examples only with strings, and I understood what you've said, and I really need a "ArrayList<int>".

Comment: I need to see the code to know why you are getting the error.

Comment: ArrayList needs to be of type Integer, ArrayList<Integer>. Generics cannot take primitive type.

Answer (score 0):

I would says, yes, let's stop and look at this a totally different way.

1) Those multidimensional arrays are take up space and aren't the most efficient way to create a lookup table - which is what you'd be using it as.
2) The lookup table is defined by an algorithm that is easy to compute, starting with 'A', each letter is given the value 1-9. The range 1-9 repeats when expires.
3) This needs to be able to handle any sort of String input from a `Scanner`, and examine each letter in the String individually.

Here's my total code suggestion:

```
String incomingString = "Ericson";

String outputValue = "";
for (int i = 0; i < incomingString.length(); i++) {
    int numberRepresentation = incomingString.charAt(i);

    if (numberRepresentation >= 'a') {
        numberRepresentation -= 'a';
    } else if (numberRepresentation >= 'A') {
        numberRepresentation -= 'A';
    } 

    numberRepresentation = (numberRepresentation % 9) + 1;

    outputValue += numberRepresentation;
}
```

---

**Explanation(s):**

1) Iteration over entire string:

```
for (int i = 0; i < incomingString.length(); i++) {
    int numberRepresentation = incomingString.charAt(i);

    // other code here 

}
```

Our incomingString variable contains the String that we're going to be doing our computation on. We create a `for` loop over each character in the String, storing the integer value of the given character into the variable numberRepresentation. This integer value is the number of where it exists on the ASCII/Unicode table.
*Optimizations/Expansions*: any String length() method calls need to be computed each time, could be extracted to a constant outside of the loop.

2) Normalize character:

```
    // other code above
    if (numberRepresentation >= 'a') {
        numberRepresentation -= 'a';
    } else if (numberRepresentation >= 'A') {
        numberRepresentation -= 'A';
    }
    // other code below
```

As you may (or may not) know, character literals can be used as integers with their value on the ASCII table. This bit of code checks if the character is lowercase (greater than or equal to the value of 'a') or uppercase (greater than or equal to the value of 'A'). By subtracting the values of 'a' or 'A', the number stored in numberRepresentation is the character's distance from 'a' in the alphabet.
*Optimizations/Expansions*: these checks only confirm that character is at least 'a' or 'A', it doesn't check to that the character is actually a letter, if it is not a letter an error should be thrown. Additionally, readability can be improved if some character methods were used.

3) Apply individual character transformation:

```
    // other code above
    numberRepresentation = (numberRepresentation % 9) + 1;
    // other code below
```

This is where the actual work is done: the modulus of each normalized character value and the number of possible values (9) is computed. As those results will be 0-8, we add one to the result to make the possible range 1-9.
*Optimizations/Expansions*: the value 9 is a constant and as such should be extracted to a local named variable. That would also allow for the encoding to change as desired i.e. if you preferred a 1-5 encoding. Removing the "+ 1" at the end of the line allows '0' to be a possible output value.

4) Append to running output:

```
    // other code above
    outputValue += numberRepresentation;
    // other code below
```

Here our new value is concatenated to the currently building String that, when finished, should be our calculated String.
*Optimizations/Expansions*: as this String concatenation is taking place within a loop, the system will constantly be creating/allocating space for new String objects. This waste can be avoided by using a StringBuilder object to combine the series of computed characters.

**Expansion**: Most importantly, if this bit of code is going to be used at multiple times, it should definitely be extracted to a method so it can be accessed easily.

---

Finished code with all expansions implemented:

```
public static String calculateName(String incomingString) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    final int encodingRange = 9;
    final int limit = incomingString.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        int numberRepresentation = incomingString.charAt(i);

        if (!Character.isLetter(numberRepresentation)) {
            throw new Exception("Incorrect String format");
        }

        if (Character.isLowerCase(numberRepresentation)) {
            numberRepresentation -= 'a';
        } else {
            numberRepresentation -= 'A';
        }

        numberRepresentation = (numberRepresentation % encodingRange) + 1;

        outputBuilder.append(numberRepresentation);
    }

    return outputBuilder.toString();
}
```